# bootstrap css make text in a div with bg image stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a bg image in a bootstrap col now my plan is to make the text in the div stick to the bottom I've tried with vertical-align but doesn't seem to be working

My html:

```
<div class="has-image col-md-6 nopadding">
            <div style="background-image: url('img/st-jansvliet.jpg');">
                <div class="stick-to-bottom">Sint Jansvliet- Antwerpen</div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

My css:

```
.stick-to-bottom{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

the div with the bg image has a height accordingly to the screen size that I set with jquery

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with a position absolute like this:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 5%;
right: 0;
top: 95%;
```

Comment: Er... `fixed` or `absolute` doesn't matter. Anyway, enjoy! `:)`

Comment: Why doesn't it matter?

Comment: When your content is less than the page width. `:P` If it is more, and you want the bottom bar to be displayed always, then fixed is better, and if it should go to the absolute bottom after the content, then you need `absolute`. Hope it is clear. `:)`

Comment: Yeah kinda :) Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 0):

Add css **position:relative** in  stick-to-bottom's Parent Div.Otherwise its possible that stick-to-bottom div sometimes outside of its Parent Div. And then add this

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0px;
right:0px;
```

It is a perfect Solution for all environment to make sure your **stick-to-bottom** remain in its parent div.